# R shiny unable to render the plot

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app for my data but my current code does not display the plot. Also based on column 8 onwards I also want to categorize my data under 2 checkboxes "Stage1" and "Stage2". And based on a dropdown, date range and checkbox show subset/filter the data and show the plot.
Stage1<-(mytest$status_2019|mytest$status_2020|mytest$status_2021|mytest$status_2022==1)
Stage2<-(mytest$status_stage2_2019|mytest$status_stage2_2020|mytest$status_stage2_2021|mytest$status_stage2_2022==1)

Here is mydata:

```
mydata<-structure(list(Id = c("DB-1", "DB-2", "DB-3", "DB-4", "DB-5", 
"DB-6", "DB-7", "DB-9", "DB-11", "DB-12", "DB-13", "DB-14", "DB-15", 
"DB-16", "DB-17", "DB-18", "DB-19", "DB-20", "DB-23", "DB-25", 
"DB-26", "DB-27", "DB-28", "DB-29", "DB-30", "DB-31", "DB-32", 
"DB-34", "DB-35", "DB-36", "DB-37"), examiner = c("Alex", "Alex", 
"Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", 
"Alex", "Alex", "Jhon", "Jhon", "Jhon", "Jhon", "Jhon", "Jhon", 
"Maymoon", "Maymoon", "Maymoon", "Maymoon", "Maymoon", "Mike", 
"Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike"), Relationship = c("sibling", 
"mother", "self", "father", "self", "self", "self", "self", "self", 
"mother", "self", "self", "self", "self", "mother", "father", 
"self", "self", "mother", "self", "self", "self", "self", "sibling", 
"father", "mother", "mother", "mother", "mother", "self", "father"
), signed_date = c("12/4/18", "11/27/18", "11/30/18", "11/13/18", 
"11/27/18", "11/13/18", "11/28/18", "2/26/19", "4/3/19", "1/15/19", 
"4/3/19", "11/13/18", "2/25/19", "12/6/18", "1/15/19", "11/30/18", 
"12/4/18", "11/20/18", "4/3/19", "2/25/19", "2/14/19", "12/6/18", 
"3/14/19", "12/7/18", "1/10/19", "3/12/19", "3/22/19", "12/20/18", 
"3/21/19", "4/5/19", "11/15/18"), gender = c("male", "female", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", 
"female", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "female", 
"male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
"male"), stage1_date = c("2/21/19 21:15", "1/10/19 21:45", "1/9/19 19:50", 
"1/10/19 21:40", "1/10/19 21:45", "1/9/20 14:50", "1/10/19 21:45", 
"3/15/19 16:50", "4/26/19 19:20", "3/21/19 18:21", "4/26/19 19:20", 
"1/10/19 21:40", "3/15/19 16:50", "1/10/19 21:45", "3/21/19 18:21", 
"1/31/19 20:25", NA, "1/10/19 21:45", "1/9/20 14:50", "7/30/19 15:10", 
"3/4/19 16:30", NA, "4/8/19 12:40", "2/6/19 20:36", "1/31/19 20:25", 
"5/1/19 18:05", "4/8/19 12:41", "1/17/19 19:26", "5/1/19 18:05", 
NA, "1/10/19 21:45"), stage2_date = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "5/11/21 17:50", 
NA, "5/21/21 17:46", NA, "5/11/21 17:37", NA, "5/21/21 17:47", 
"5/15/21 16:07", "5/16/21 16:07", NA, NA, NA, "5/11/21 17:52", 
NA, NA, "5/14/21 16:07", "5/11/21 17:37", "5/11/21 17:52", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "5/11/21 17:42", NA), status_2019 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), status_2020 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), status_2021 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    status_2022 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), status_stage2_2020 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), status_stage2_2021 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), status_stage2_2022 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -31L
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Onboarded = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Relationship = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), signed_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), stage1_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), stage2_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), status_2019 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), status_2020 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), status_2021 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), status_2022 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), status_stage2_2020 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), status_stage2_2021 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), status_stage2_2022 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x7f7f0a7dc7c0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
mydata <- read_csv("test.csv")
mydata$signed_date <- as.Date(mydata$signed_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d", optional=FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$examiner)
    mydata %>% 
      dplyr::filter(examiner %in% input$examiner ,
                    signed_date >= input$daterange[1] &
                      signed_date <= input$daterange[2]) %>%
      group_by(relation) %>% summarize(Total = n())
    
  })
  output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have chosen ", input$examiner, "between", input$Dates[1], "and", input$Dates[2])
  }) 
  #Plot 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes( y = Total, x = relation))
    g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  titlePanel("My Dashboard"),
  helpText("Shows my data"),
  selectInput(inputId = "examiner",
              label = h3("Choose examiner"),
              choices = c("None", as.character(mydata$examiner), selected = "None")),
  dateRangeInput("Dates", h3("Select the Dates"), format="yyyy-mm-dd", start = "2018-04-01"),
  
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("selected_var"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am now running into the following error
Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
[34mℹ[39m Input `..1` is `examiner %in% input$examiner`.
[31mx[39m object 'examiner' not found

Comment: Instead of `choices = c("None", as.character(mydata$examiner))` try `choices = c("None", unique(mydata$examiner))`

Comment: This didn't work!

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems:

1. Typos
2. Your date data is not in a standard date format
3. Your posted data had an error in it.

I've begun to clean up some of these typos, but I'll leave you to figure out the date issue. The below has a `browser()` statement in one of the reactives. Run the app and then work interactively at the R console to see the date problem (by running something like `class(mydata$stage1_date)`. Once you clean up the date problem post better data.

Here's something that is a little closer.

```
mydata <-
  structure(
    list(
      Id = c(
        "DB-1",
        "DB-2",
        "DB-3",
        "DB-4",
        "DB-5",
        "DB-6",
        "DB-7",
        "DB-9",
        "DB-11",
        "DB-12",
        "DB-13",
        "DB-14",
        "DB-15",
        "DB-16",
        "DB-17",
        "DB-18",
        "DB-19",
        "DB-20",
        "DB-23",
        "DB-25",
        "DB-26",
        "DB-27",
        "DB-28",
        "DB-29",
        "DB-30",
        "DB-31",
        "DB-32",
        "DB-34",
        "DB-35",
        "DB-36",
        "DB-37"
      ),
      examiner = c(
        "Alex",
        "Alex",
        "Alex",
        "Alex",
        "Alex",
        "Alex",
        "Kim",
        "Kim",
        "Kim",
        "Kim",
        "Kim",
        "Alex",
        "Alex",
        "Jhon",
        "Jhon",
        "Jhon",
        "Jhon",
        "Jhon",
        "Jhon",
        "Maymoon",
        "Maymoon",
        "Maymoon",
        "Maymoon",
        "Maymoon",
        "Mike",
        "Mike",
        "Mike",
        "Mike",
        "Mike",
        "Mike",
        "Mike"
      ),
      Relationship = c(
        "sibling",
        "mother",
        "self",
        "father",
        "self",
        "self",
        "self",
        "self",
        "self",
        "mother",
        "self",
        "self",
        "self",
        "self",
        "mother",
        "father",
        "self",
        "self",
        "mother",
        "self",
        "self",
        "self",
        "self",
        "sibling",
        "father",
        "mother",
        "mother",
        "mother",
        "mother",
        "self",
        "father"
      ),
      application_date = c(
        "12/4/18",
        "11/27/18",
        "11/30/18",
        "11/13/18",
        "11/27/18",
        "11/13/18",
        "11/28/18",
        "2/26/19",
        "4/3/19",
        "1/15/19",
        "4/3/19",
        "11/13/18",
        "2/25/19",
        "12/6/18",
        "1/15/19",
        "11/30/18",
        "12/4/18",
        "11/20/18",
        "4/3/19",
        "2/25/19",
        "2/14/19",
        "12/6/18",
        "3/14/19",
        "12/7/18",
        "1/10/19",
        "3/12/19",
        "3/22/19",
        "12/20/18",
        "3/21/19",
        "4/5/19",
        "11/15/18"
      ),
      gender = c(
        "male",
        "female",
        "male",
        "male",
        "male",
        "male",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "male",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "male",
        "male",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "male",
        "male",
        "female",
        "male",
        "male",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "female",
        "male"
      ),
      stage1_date = c(
        "2/21/19 21:15",
        "1/10/19 21:45",
        "1/9/19 19:50",
        "1/10/19 21:40",
        "1/10/19 21:45",
        "1/9/20 14:50",
        "1/10/19 21:45",
        "3/15/19 16:50",
        "4/26/19 19:20",
        "3/21/19 18:21",
        "4/26/19 19:20",
        "1/10/19 21:40",
        "3/15/19 16:50",
        "1/10/19 21:45",
        "3/21/19 18:21",
        "1/31/19 20:25",
        NA,
        "1/10/19 21:45",
        "1/9/20 14:50",
        "7/30/19 15:10",
        "3/4/19 16:30",
        NA,
        "4/8/19 12:40",
        "2/6/19 20:36",
        "1/31/19 20:25",
        "5/1/19 18:05",
        "4/8/19 12:41",
        "1/17/19 19:26",
        "5/1/19 18:05",
        NA,
        "1/10/19 21:45"
      ),
      stage2_date = c(
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "5/11/21 17:50",
        NA,
        "5/21/21 17:46",
        NA,
        "5/11/21 17:37",
        NA,
        "5/21/21 17:47",
        "5/15/21 16:07",
        "5/16/21 16:07",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "5/11/21 17:52",
        NA,
        NA,
        "5/14/21 16:07",
        "5/11/21 17:37",
        "5/11/21 17:52",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "5/11/21 17:42",
        NA
      ),
      status_2019 = c(
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        1
      ),
      status_2020 = c(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ),
      status_2021 = c(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ),
      status_2022 = c(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ),
      status_stage2_2020 = c(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ),
      status_stage2_2021 = c(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0
      ),
      status_stage2_2022 = c(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -31L),
    spec = structure(list(
      cols = list(
        Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                         "collector")),
        Onboarded = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                                "collector")),
        Relationship = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                                   "collector")),
        application_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                                       "collector")),
        gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                             "collector")),
        stage1_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                                  "collector")),
        stage2_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                                  "collector")),
        status_2019 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                  "collector")),
        status_2020 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                  "collector")),
        status_2021 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                  "collector")),
        status_2022 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                  "collector")),
        status_stage2_2020 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                         "collector")),
        status_stage2_2021 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                         "collector")),
        status_stage2_2022 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                         "collector"))
      ),
      default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                            "collector")),
      delim = ","
    ), class = "col_spec"),
    # problems = < pointer:0x7f7f0a7dc7c0 > ,
    class = c("spec_tbl_df",
              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
# mydata <- read_csv("test.csv")
mydata$signed_date <-
  as.Date(mydata$signed_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d", optional = FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    
    req(input$examiner)
    browser()
    mydata %>%
      dplyr::filter(
        examiner %in% input$examiner ,
        stage1_date >= input$daterange[1] &
          stage1_date <= input$daterange[2]
      ) %>%
      group_by(Relationship) %>% summarize(Total = n())
    
  })
  output$selected_var <- renderText({
    paste("You have chosen ",
          input$examiner,
          "between",
          input$Dates[1],
          "and",
          input$Dates[2])
  })
  #Plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes(y = Total, x = relation))
    g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  titlePanel("My Dashboard"),
  helpText("Shows my data"),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "examiner",
    label = h3("Choose examiner"),
    choices = c("None", as.character(mydata$examiner), selected = "None")
  ),
  dateRangeInput(
    "daterange",
    h3("Select the Dates"),
    format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
    start = "2018-04-01"
  ),
  
  mainPanel(textOutput("selected_var"),
            plotOutput("plot"))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I see this as a date when I run class(mydata$stage1_date)
[1] "Date"

Comment: It seems you updated other parts of the app, b/c when I run the code above it returns character. I suggest isolating the problem and asking a new *specific* question.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many typos in your code as noted by @dca.  Try this

```
mydata$signed_date <- as.Date(mydata$application_date, format = "%m/%d/%y", optional=FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    #req(input$examiner)
    if (is.null(input$examiner) | input$examiner=="None") return(NULL)
    
    mydata %>% dplyr::filter(examiner %in% input$examiner) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(signed_date >= input$Dates[1] & signed_date <= input$Dates[2]) %>%
      group_by(Relationship) %>% dplyr::summarize(Total = n())
    
  })
  output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have chosen ", input$examiner, "between", input$Dates[1], "and", input$Dates[2])
  }) 
  #Plot 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(data())
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes( y = Total, x = Relationship))
    g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  titlePanel("My Dashboard"),
  helpText("Shows my data"),
  selectInput(inputId = "examiner",
              label = h3("Choose examiner"),
              choices = c("None", unique(mydata$examiner)), selected = "None"),
  dateRangeInput("Dates", h3("Select the Dates"), format="yyyy-mm-dd", start = "2018-04-01"),
  
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("selected_var"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```